# How to find a basic shape, with OpenCV in React Native

Tags: c++, react-native, opencv, contour

My Goal is to find a basic shape in React Native.

I am using:

- React native CLI ("react-native": "0.67.3")

  - react-native-opencv3 -  https://github.com/adamgf/react-native-opencv3

How I can create an OutputArrayOfArrays type (vector<vector<Point  counters;) In  React Native?

I would like to use OpenCV [findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) and [drawContours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc) in react native to find a basic shape (circle, rect, triangle)

The purpose of the contours are to represent the corners location of the shape.
Each corner is represented by two points, here is the structure:

vector<vector<Point  counters;

in c++

```
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > counters;
```

**In The React Native code side of react-native-opencv3 api**
in the [HOUGHCIRCLES example:](https://github.com/adamgf/react-native-opencv3-tests/blob/master/HoughCircles/App.js) params are passing with p1,p2... as type  {MAT, DOUBLE, FLOAT, INT, BOOLEAN, STR, SCALAR, POINT, SIZE, RECT}

```
const {interMat, circlesMat} = this.state;
if (interMat && circlesMat) {
  return (
    <CvInvoke
      func="HoughCircles" //cornerHarris
      params={{
        p1: interMat,
        p2: circlesMat,
        p3: 3,
        p4: 2,
        p5: 320,
      }}
```

in the **react-native-opencv3 api** implementation types available are:
enum {MAT, DOUBLE, FLOAT, INT, BOOLEAN, STR, SCALAR, POINT, SIZE, RECT} tag;

```
Mat m;
double d;
float f;
int i;
bool b;
const char *str;
Scalar sc;
cv::Point pt;
cv::Size sz;
cv::Rect r;
```

**On Xcode**
in the HOUGHCIRCLES function example:

```
case HOUGHCIRCLES: {
        auto p1 = args[0].m;
        auto p2 = args[1].m;
        auto p3 = args[2].i;
        auto p4 = args[3].d;
        auto p5 = args[4].d;
        HoughCircles(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
        return p2;
    }
```

To use the OpenCV findContours use OutputArrayOfArrays type (vector<vector<Point  counters;)

[image]

```
    findContours(image, counters, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

How can I implement the findContours OpenCV function with react-native-opencv3?

Is there another way to find a shape with React Native?

Thanks.